# "textLength" changes on hover for svg text elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, text, svg, hover

I'm using svg-text-elements for a Website Layout and i'm changing the textLength-attribute to get alle the Menu items in a Menu to have the same length. (When you change textLength the spacing is automatically adjusted and the letters keep their size)

```
<div class="menu-item">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <text class="hover-black" lengthAdjust="spacing" fill="black">AGENDA</text>
        </svg>
</div>
```

"textLength" and positioning is done in JavaScript.

It's all working fine, except that in Internet Explorer the textLength-Attributs seem to be erased when i hover over the Menu-Text, and the svg-text i'm hovering over flips back in standard spacing.

There's nothing set in CSS nor JS for the hovering...

Perhaps somebody has an idea, thanks a lot!

EDIT: Solved! 
Sorry for bothering you guys. I found a:

```
.menu-item { 
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer
    }  
}
```

which i overlooked in the css. Seems to be a bug in IE.

Comment: I added a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f32jt9w/  If you click the text it changes spacing...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style="pointer-events:none"` to the actual text tag. That should fix it in IE11 at least. I ran into a similar issue with IE acting weird while using lenghtAdjust in SVGs.

So you altogether it would look like this :

```
<div class="menu-item">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <text class="hover-black" x="30" y="30" textLength="250" fill="black" style="pointer-events:none">AGENDA</text>
      </svg>
</div>
```

I've tried doing it with a class and that doesn't work either. Only when I added it to the text tag as inline CSS.

It was still acting weird with the `cursor:pointer` for me. To reproduce the issue, try double-clicking on the text in IE. It'll jump to the right or left. If this is a navigation item, then you would need to do an active link (rect maybe?) below the text and `pointer-events:none` already allows you to click through the text.